# Problemas para realizar una carga masiva en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

resulta que tengo creada la siguiente tabla:

```
cabtm char (3) not null,
cabdoc char(8) not null,
cabdat date,
cabven char (3) not null,
cabcli char (12) not null,
primary key (cabtm,cabdoc),
index cabecera_fkindex1(cabven),
foreign key(cabven)
references vendedor (codven)
on delete no action,
index cabecera_fkindex2 (cabcli),
foreign key (cabcli)
references cliente (codcli)
on delete no action);
```

y necesito realizar una carga masiva de dtos pero me aparece

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`actividad1`.`cabecera`, CONSTRAINT
>   `cabecera_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`cabcli`) REFERENCES `cliente`
>   (`codcli`) ON DELETE NO ACTION),

ya he buscado y no encuentro el error, me podrìan ayudar? Gracias

Comment: Hola, una pregunta tonta pero cuando realizas la carga masiva de datos estas teniendo en cuenta que el dato de la columna cabcli no puede ser nulo ?

Comment: En tus datos que insertas existe un dato en cabcli que no existe en la tabla cliente columna codcli, revisa los datos que intentas insertar buscando cuál no existe.

Comment: Se intenta insertar un dato en la columna `cabcli` que no existe en la columna `codcli` de la tabla `cliente`. Esa situación viola la restricción siguiente: `foreign key (cabcli) references cliente (codcli) on delete no action` y por eso salta el error. **Todo valor** que intentes insertar en la columna `cabcli` debe existir previamente en la columna `codcli` de la tabla `cliente`.

Answer (score 0):

Los errores que te dan van referidos a que intentas crear los datos de esa tabla SIN tener creados los datos de las tablas referidas.

Para solucionarlo, tienes un par de soluciones:

1.- busca todos los INSERT de las tablas CLIENTE y VENDEDOR, y ponlos ANTES de los INSERT de la tabla que te da problemas. El orden es importante en la mayoria de los casos, pues deben existir valores en algunas tablas ANTES de crear los de otras que tengan dependencias.

2.- Desactiva la validacion de los **Foreign_keys**. 
    a) ejecuta "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;"; para desactivar la validacion
    b) ejecuta todos los insert que tengas de tu carga masiva
    c) ejecuta "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"; para activar de nuevo las validaciones

**CUIDADO!!!**

**CUIDADO!!!**

**CUIDADO!!!**

la segunda opcion, aunque valida, es bastante peligrosa, si en tu carga masiva tienes valores en la tabla que te da problemas, que no corresponden a valores de CLIENTE ni VENDEDOR. Esto puede provocar inconsistencia en tu BBDD.
Así que, en caso de que necesites utilizar la segunda opción, **ASEGURATE** que  los datos de tus tablas son correctos.